# "Advanced Network Compression" is not working on Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, tnsnames

it seems to me that the Compression is not working on our System (*Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production*).
I've made the configuration with this [Oracle Whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/advancednetworkcompression-2141325.pdf).

Serverside Configuration (*sqlnet.ora*):

```
SQLNET.COMPRESSION = on
SQLNET.COMPRESSION_LEVELS = high
SQLNET.COMPRESSION_THRESHOLD = 1024
```

Clientside Configuration (*tnsnames.ora*):

```
MY12C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE)
    )
  )

MY12C_COMP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (COMPRESSION=on)
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE)
    )
  )
```

Testscript for SQLPLUS (Version *SQLPlus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production*):

```
set serveroutput on
set linesize 2000

--Package only used to save statistic value
create or replace package sesStat is
    startVal number;
end;
/

--Save statistic value
begin
select ms.value into sesstat.startVal from v$mystat ms, v$statname sn where ms.statistic#=sn.statistic# and sn.name='bytes sent via SQL*Net to client';
end;
/

--Query which delivers lot of Data
SELECT to_char(lpad('xxx', 3500, level)) as col
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 499;

--generating some Output
declare
val number;
cVersion varchar2(100);
bnr varchar2(100);
begin
select distinct client_version into cVersion from V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO where sid=sys_context('USERENV', 'SID');
select banner into bnr from v$version where rownum=1;
select ms.value -sesstat.startVal into val from v$mystat ms, v$statname sn where ms.statistic#=sn.statistic# and sn.name='bytes sent via SQL*Net to client';
dbms_output.put_line('ClientVersion: ('||cVersion||') Server-Version: ('||bnr||') Sent Data: '||val/1024||' kb');
end;
/
```

Testing:
call the Testscript against MY12C and MY12C_COMP delivers exact the same Output:

```
ClientVersion: (12.1.0.1.0) Server-Version: (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production) Sent Data: 1714,4111328125 kb
```

My expectation is, that it should be less data sent if i start the testscript against the TNS-Entry with the "Compression=on" clause.

What am i doing wrong?